# Java equivalent of .NET object.Equals(object, object)

Tags: java, equals, equality

In .NET `System.Object` defines a static method

```
bool Equals(object a, object b);
```

That is a useful alternative to `a.Equals(b)` in cases where `a` may be `null`.  It also returns true if both `a` and `b` are `null`.

I can't find an equivalent method in Java's framework (my Java is a bit rusty these days.)  The most succinct code I can muster is:

```
(a==null && b==null) || (a!=null && a.Equals(b))
```

Does such a method exist?

**NOTE** I don't want to take a dependency on any external framework.  I'm just curious if this simple method exists in the core Java class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this does not exist in the core library, but it is one of the improvements that is being added with Java 1.7.

In Java 1.7, you can use `Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)`.  Until then, I recommend implementing it yourself if you do not want to add an external dependency.

[source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks very much for a definitive answer on this.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is [ObjectUtils.equals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

```
 ObjectUtils.equals(null, null)                  = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(null, "")                    = false
 ObjectUtils.equals("", null)                    = false
 ObjectUtils.equals("", "")                      = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, null)          = false
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, "true")        = false
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE)  = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE) = false
```

If you are interested, here is the code from the library...

```
public static boolean equals(Object object1, Object object2) {
    if (object1 == object2) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((object1 == null) || (object2 == null)) {
        return false;
    }
    return object1.equals(object2);
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to take a dependency on an external library just for this one simple method.  Does this really not exist in the core class library?

Comment: No, this is not in the core; some would argue both ways on if it should be. I have updated my answer with the code from the library which you could just use as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  I have added a method similar to the one you show in my codebase.

Answer (score 1):

[ObjectUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html) in [Apache Common](http://commons.apache.org/)s provides such a [method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).